# AFNetworking responseobejct problems in getting to see the dictionary

Tags: objective-c, io, afnetworking-2

All,

I am trying to retrieve objects from the response object in `AFNetworking`, I don't think the response object is a dictionary but I am sure it is.

Here is my code :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:returncompletedURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // 3
    NSString *value = responseObject[@"logo"];

    NSLog(@"%@", value);
```

I am just getting the result (null) from my `NSLog`. logo is in the JSON when I just show the JSON.

thanks

```
complete = 1;
    data =     (
                {
            ID = 1;
            address = "14 avon road";
            address2 = "";
            bar = 0;
            barID = 1;
            club = 0;
            content = dsgsdf;
            date = "2014-02-12";
            finish = "2014-02-13 00:00:00";
            logo = "http://outtonightapp.com/uploads/terrace.jpg";
            name = Gre;
            postcode = le33aa;
            restaurant = 1;
            send = "2014-02-07 00:00:00";
            start = "2014-02-05 00:00:00";
        },
                {
            ID = 2;
            address = "14 avon road";
            address2 = "";
            bar = 1;
            barID = 1;
            club = 0;
            content = dsgsdf;
            date = "2014-02-12";
            finish = "2014-02-13 00:00:00";
            logo = "http://outtonightapp.com/uploads/terrace.jpg";
            name = Gre;
            postcode = le33aa;
            restaurant = 0;
            send = "2014-02-07 00:00:00";
            start = "2014-02-05 00:00:00";
        }
    );
    rows = 3;
```

Here is the output of JSON when just ran

```
NSLog(@"%@",response object);
```

Comment: Log whole response object and see what it's NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

Comment: Are you sure that "logo" is a string? Are you sure the response object is a dictionary? Log out those and then update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your case `responseObject` is dictionary with two values: 'complete' (NSNumber) and 'data' (NSArray of NSDictionaries). To get all logos you can just call

```
NSArray * allLogos = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"logo"]
```

or get all nested objects and find appropriate logo between them

```
NSArray * allNestedObjects = [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of nsdictionary, try that:

```
for (NSDictionary * dict in responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"logo"]);
}
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e7f450' - ERROR when i do that